# Topologizing free abelian groups. Clarification

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

The question [Topologizing free abelian groups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19829/topologizing-free-abelian-groups) on `Mathoverflow` asks about the existence and uniqueness of a topology for the free abelian group on $X$ such that the natural inclusion is a homeomorphism onto its image and addition and inverse map are continuous.

There are four different answers and some interesting discussions along the comments.
The final answer is affirmative if and only if the topological space is completely regular.
In the Abelian case (as in others) it can be regarded as $\mathbb Z[X]$ endowed with the weakest topology with respect to which all homomorphic extensions of continuous maps from $X$ to topological groups are continuous (Sipacheva, *Free Boolean Topological Groups*).

The topology on these spaces is important because their homotopy groups compute the homology with integer coefficients of the topological spaces they're the span of (Dold-Thom theorem).

In this sense, McCord provided a systematic construction of abelian groups whose homotopy groups computed the homology of the space in question with coefficients in ''good'' groups (I think there are some technical conditions).
For a (pointed) space $(X,x_0)$ and a topological abelian group $G$, $B(G,X)$ was the space of functions $f:X\to G$ with finite support with the extra convention that $f(x_0)=e$ for all $f$.

For each $n\geq 0$ $B_n(G,X)$ was the subspace of $B(G,X)$ consisting of functions whose support had at most cardinality $n$, with the quotient topology with respect to the map

$$
q_n:(X\times G)^n \to B_n(G,X);
$$

$q((g_1,x_1),\dots,(g_n,x_n))$ is the function $f:X\to G$ such that $f(x_i)=g_i$ and $f(x)=e$ for $x\in X\setminus \{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ (with the convention that $q(g,x_0)=e$ for all $g\in G$.
Then

$$
B(G,X)= \bigcup_n B_n(G,X).
$$

For $G=\mathbb Z$ with the discrete topology, $B(\mathbb Z,X)$ is the group completion of the topological monoid $SP^\infty X$, the infinite symmetric product of $X$.

> Is $B(\mathbb Z,X)$ isomorphic to $\mathbb Z[X]$ as topological abelian groups?

> In the paper (Sipacheva,*Free Boolean Topological Groups*), the author defines free Boolean topological groups are defined similarly: the abstract free Boolean group generated by the set $X$ endowed with the weakest topology with respect to which all homomorphic extensions of continuous maps from $X$ to topological Boolean groups are continuous.
> Is this equivalent to $B(\mathbb Z_2,X)$?

$\bullet$ M. C. McCord, *Classifying spaces and infinite symmetric products*.

**EDIT**

As @Tyrone points out in a comment, McCord considers compactly generated spaces. In the accepted answer to the original question, the space $X$ must be normal for the *free* abelian topological group $\mathbb Z[X]$ to exist. You can assume that all the spaces here are locally finite CW-complexes.

Comment: The $B(\mathbb{Z},X)$ aren't even topological groups as McCord works exclusively with compactly generated spaces. However, according to the material in $\S7$ of his paper, $B(\mathbb{Z},X)$ will be a topological group whenever $X$ is a countable CW complex. In any case, you will need further restrictions on your spaces if you do not want your questions to have trivial negative answers.

Comment: Oh yes, I'm sorry. In my head $X$ was a CW-complex all the time. I'll add this remark to the question.

Comment: @Tyrone What further restrictions?

Comment: I think that locally-finite CW complex is a good assumption!

Comment: @Tyrone Okay, thank you.

Comment: I asked the non-abelian analogue of this question on MO some time ago. (Sorry 
I got the link wrong the first time!) https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273297/the-group-analogue-of-the-james-construction

Comment: @JeremyBrazas I think in the abelian seeting $SP^\infty X$ would correspond to the James construction and $F_G(X)$ should be $B(\mathbb Z,X)$ (I didn't know what Graev group was, so I've taken the definition from the first paper that's come up, (New metrics on free groups)[https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81989505.pdf]. The topology there is directly given in terms of a metric, but I think that's Ok)... (TBC)

Comment: ... The answer to your answer in this abelian case is yes, since $SP^\infty X$ and $B(\mathbb Z, X)$ have the same homotopy type. I don't see any reason why this can't be the case in the non-abelian frame. After all, $F_G(X)$ seems to be the completion of the monoid $J(X)$. It should be known if a topological monoid and its completion have the same homotopy type.

Comment: @Dog_69 There are lots of topologies one can put on free groups but that of $F_G(X)$ is unique and it is never metrizable when $X$ is non-discrete (even when $X$ is metrizable). The same is going to be true of free topological abelian groups. The topology of these universal topological groups is a messy business with a big literature.

Comment: @JeremyBrazas Yes, very true. I've been trying to find well-known facts on this subject for a few days and it's a nightmare. I think it's partially due to the fact that the problem is looked from point-set toplogy, where weird counterexamples are always possible. But I'm more interested in nice spaces, and no one seems to have think exclusively about them. Regarding your comment about metrizability, I didn't know it. I must assumed that metric the authors where considering would induced the the same toplogy. However, both spaces might have the same homotopy type... That'd be enough for me.